# Apache2 mod_php in virtual machine shared folder code using non existent file

Tags: php, git, apache, virtual-machine

I tried to setup a development environment where my server environment is emulated by virtual machine running centos 6.3 and development is done from host OS. The application code (codeigniter app) is in a shared folder mounted to /home/foo/Desktop/code/app and I have created a virtual host in apache to serve this application.

On the development side, git is used as the VCS .

The problem is that when loading a helper two files are being included. Eg, I have a helper in application/helper named my_date_helper. It has two functions. I autoload this helper.

When running this application php throws this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare time12to24() (previously declared in /home/mlakhara/code/cosys/application/helpers/my_date_helper.php:9) in /home/mlakhara/code/cosys/application/helpers/MY_date_helper.php on line 11
```

When I comment the function, it says the functions are undefined.

Also the time related functions throw a warning telling me to set a timezone which I have already in the php.ini file using date.timezone option.

I assumed that these two files can be same included twice with different names, but the line numbers suggest something else.. (function is declared at different lines).

The application functions correctly when served from normal folder (non shared). I removed git from the vn and tried but it did not make any difference.

What can be the problem ?

---------------EDIT -----------------------
Taking hints from Magnus Eriksson's answer, I found that I was autoloading these 'extended' helpers instead of loading the actual path and date helpers. This lead to getting two copies of the same function. However the problem with timezone setting still persists.

As a corrective measure I added the time value to my .htaccess file as well. However is there any better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing "my_" in the filename. CodeIgniter uses "MY_" to extend the core and might test with both lower and upper case and thus loading the same file twice.

Either way, as Rob W pointed out, always wrap your helper functions in `if (!function_exists()) {}`

About the timezone problem: Since I haven't seen your php.ini or your setup, I can't say why it isn't working.
One solution should be to add `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` (or what timezone you want) first thing in index.php.

Since I don't always have access to modify php.ini on clients production servers, I usually add that in.

Comment: Well done Magnus, you solved the main part of the question. And for that I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the timezone question.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the function twice. When including the files, try using `require_once('path/to/file.php')` instead of `include` or `require`. Otherwise, in the source file, you can do:

```
if(!function_exists("time12to24")) {
  function time12to24() [...]
}
```

Comment: but the other file is not even present in the application. If I comment the function, it says function undefined.